# How to draw a rectangle which displays perpendicular to its parent QGraphicsLineItem at any instance

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsLineItem on the scene. This line item can be rotated on the scene using either of its end points as an anchor. Basically this line can rotated and resized. I want to draw a rectangle such that it always intersects the parent line at 90 degrees. The rectangle should remain perpendicular to the line at any given instant.The rectangle's points topLeft, topRight should lie on one side of the line while bottomLeft & bottomRight should lie on the other side of the line. I tried the below code but the rectangle does not render itself perpendicular to the line. In reality, I intend to show a rectangular image perpendicular to the line, this image can be resized too. I badly need to get this right.Can anybody answer this question please?

```
void PersonSizeGraphicsItem::paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{

    CustomGraphicsLineItem* parent_line_item = dynamic_cast<CustomGraphicsLineItem *>(parent_item);
    if(parent_line_item == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    QPen myPen = parent_line_item->pen();
    myPen.setColor(Qt::red);
    painter->setPen(myPen);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QLineF parent_line = parent_line_item->line();
    QLineF normal_vector_line = parent_line.normalVector();
    normal_vector_line.setLength(30.0);

    QPointF first_line_base_point = parent_line.pointAt(0.4);

    QPointF _p1 = first_line_base_point -(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());
    QPointF _p2 = first_line_base_point +(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());

    QLineF rect_line_one = normal_vector_line;
    rect_line_one.setP1(_p1);
    rect_line_one.setP2(_p2);

    QPointF second_line_base_point = parent_line.pointAt(0.7);

    QPointF _p3 = second_line_base_point -(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());
    QPointF _p4 = second_line_base_point +(normal_vector_line.p1()-normal_vector_line.p2());

    QLineF rect_line_two = normal_vector_line;
    rect_line_two.setP1(_p3);
    rect_line_two.setP2(_p4);

    //QRect image_rect( rect_line_one.p1().toPoint(), QSize(30, 60));
    QRect image_rect;
    image_rect.setTopLeft( rect_line_one.p1().toPoint());
    //image_rect.setBottomLeft( rect_line_one.p2().toPoint());
    //image_rect.setTopRight(rect_line_two.p1().toPoint());
    image_rect.setBottomRight(rect_line_two.p2().toPoint());

    painter->drawRect(image_rect);

    //painter->drawLine(rect_line_one);
    //painter->drawLine(rect_line_two);
    //painter->drawImage(image_rect, source_image);
}
```

Comment: Can anybdy answer my question please?

Comment: Can't you just make the rectangle a graphics item and make the line its parent item?

Comment: Merlin069 - My intention is not to draw a rectangle but to display the image which needs the target rectangle for the method QPainter's drawImage(). Its just that I am testing by rendering a rectangle item.In reality I need to display my image across the parent item.

Comment: Can you add an image to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: Merlin069 - I am facing even bigger problem currently. There is a parent child relationship between two items. The child item which is a QGraphicsPixmapItem(image) was receiving all the events independently. But when I make a QGraphicsLIneItem as its parent and rendered the image wrt parent item, I am unable to receive any event for the child. Please help, why is it happening?

Comment: Merlin069 - I have raised a separate question for the above issue. Could you please kindly respond to it?